# Why don't matplotlib recognize my timestamp on xaxis?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

Right now Im trying to figure out how `Matplotlib` and `Pandas` work by processing a dataset with movements out/in a birdnest. I successfully plotted the full dataset as an line graph with an xaxis as timestamp.

However when Im trying to plot a set interval as a barchart (grouped by hour) matplotlib no longer recognize the `xaxis` as a timestamp, so i can't use formatters and locators correctly (`HourLocator` etc.).

The index of my dataframe is a timestamp, however it seems to loose it properties as a timestamp when i use the `.groupby()` function.

```py
newdf = df[date:(date+forward*deltaday)]
bx = newdf['Movements'].groupby(pd.Grouper( freq='H')).sum().plot.bar()
xtick_locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
xtick_formatter = mdates.AutoDateFormatter(xtick_locator) 
bx.xaxis.set_major_locator(xtick_locator)
bx.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xtick_formatter)
```

When running this code i get the following error messages:

> ValueError: view limit minimum -0.5 is less than 1 and is an invalid
>   Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime
>   value to an axis that has datetime units"

Which indicates that my `xaxis` is not `datetime` object anymore. When fetching my `xticks` labels with `xticks()` i get following:

`Text(0, 0, '2015-02-02 00:00:00')`...
`Text(47, 0, '2015-02-03 23:00:00')`

It looks like an timestamp but matplotlib won't recognize it as one. Without any expertise knowledge i believe it `.groupby()` who is the bandit.

**Is there a better way to plot a barchart with the sum of df['Movements'] per hour plotted for a set time interval?**

(`df['Movements']` is right now movements per minute)

Comment: This is not a matplotlib problem. I suppose a matplotlib bar plot would work fine. But pandas bar plots are categorical and do not care about the actual date.